# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'truncate'. within a View

Tags: t-sql

I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'truncate'." and not sure what's wrong with the syntax here, it's not obvious to me...probably something stupid but I need another set of eyes:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_All_Events]
AS

truncate table Event

Select [event_id]
      ,[site_id]
      ,[autogenerated]
      ,[creation_date]
      ,[last_update_date]
from Event

GO
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?  the truncate doesn't make any sense in this context

Comment: Even if this syntax were valid and would work - then your view would never be showing any data (since that's just been truncated away). So what exactly are you trying to get done here?? Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense at all ....

Comment: just trying to clear the table as this view is used in SSIS as the select data to insert back into the same table.

Comment: There won't be any data to insert back... You cleared it all. We are all mystified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view only allows a single statement after the `AS` and it must be data retrieval (return a rowset). It can't be a different type including data definition, data modification, procedural, declarative, or any other.

You *can* do these things with a stored procedure, or a user-defined function (but can't do DDL & DML in a function).

In detail, a stored procedure allows flow-of-control statements like IF THEN ELSE BEGIN END WHILE RETURN. You can use DML to UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT. You can use DDL to CREATE and DROP tables and indexes, add columns and constraints, and so on. You can return multiple rowsets. You can execute dynamic SQL.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yea I'll just have my SSIS transactions call procs, that way I can clear the table then call my view (Select the data)...

Comment: Why do you need a view that is only used to return an empty rowset?

Answer (score 1):

Better way, you use a stored procedure instead of view.

There are you write multiple statement and also get output.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have select statements in views. Therefore, 'truncate' is an invalid command to use.

Answer (score -1):

`TRUNCATE` does not work with views.

Check out this [link](http://lists.mysql.com/commits/24323)